# How can you specify UI port for lite-server?

Tags: lite-server

When you start up lite-server, you can specify port for example

```
lite-server -- port 8000
```

Which gives you the following result:

```
[BS] Access URLs:
 ------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:8000
    External: http://192.168.0.5:8000
 ------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.0.5:3001
```

How can I change the port for UI which is 3001 by default (either command line and/or in bs-config.json file), to like 8001?

Comment: https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server#custom-configuration ...

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it doesn't explain how to change the UI port - only the Local port which I have set in the example with -- port 8000 tag

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 18):

Since lite-server uses browsersync, it can be changed via [BrowserSync options](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/)

Not sure about command line parameter, but `bs-config.json` works like this:

```
{
  "port": 8000,
  "files": ["./dist/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}"],
  "server": { "baseDir": "./" },
  "ui": {
    "port": 8001
  }
}
```

[BrowserSync command line options (that also work with lite-server)](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/command-line/)

Answer (score 16):

Just to add, for slow thinkers like me, to run lite-server on different port, create file *bs-config.json* in root of your project (or wherever you are running lite-server from) and add this into your *bs-config.json*

```
{
    "port": 8080
}
```

this will run lite server on port 8080

alternatively you can just pass path of the bs-config.json on running lite-server

```
lite-server -c configs/my-bs-config.json
```

source: https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server#custom-configuration