# How do I change the the default lite-server port in Angular quickstart?

Tags: node.js, angular, lite-server

I just downloaded Angular 4 quickstart app and attempted to change the default lite-server port by adding `"port": 8000` to `bs-config.json` as following:

```
{
  "server": {
    "port": 8000,
    "baseDir": "src",
    "routes": {
      "/node_modules": "node_modules"
    }
  }
}
```

When I `npm start` the app I see that `bs-config.json` is read OK, but `lite-server` still continues with the default port 3000

```
 >angular-quickstart@1.0.0 serve /Users/me/code/quickstart
[1] > lite-server -c=bs-config.json
[1] 
[1] ** browser-sync config **
[1] { injectChanges: false,
[1]   files: [ './**/*.{html,htm,css,js}' ],
[1]   watchOptions: { ignored: 'node_modules' },
[1]   server: 
[1]    { baseDir: 'src',
[1]      middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ],
[1]      port: 8000,
[1]      routes: { '/node_modules': 'node_modules' } } }
[1] [BS] Access URLs:
[1]  -------------------------------------
[1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
[1]     External: http://192.168.1.12:3000
[1]  -------------------------------------
[1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
[1]  UI External: http://192.168.1.12:3001
[1]  -------------------------------------
[1] [BS] Serving files from: src
[1] [BS] Watching files...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35516783/how-can-you-specify-ui-port-for-lite-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [the documentation](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-port), you should declare a port as a top level:

```
{
  "port": 8000,
  "server": {
    "baseDir": "src",
    "routes": {
      "/node_modules": "node_modules"
    }
  }
}
```