# http-server -p 8080 does not serve my angular application. Whereas ng serve does

Tags: angular, angular6

[This is what I see when I open my localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgKOL.png)

I want to make a PWA with Angular so I followed the instructions on the  [angular.io website](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#serving-with-http-server) to the smallest detail yet it doesn't open the usual "Welcome to your app" page. What might be the problem?

I am have the following installed:

Angular CLI: 6.0.1
Node: 8.9.4
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.0.1

[This is what the console displays when i click on pwaApp and the browser  directs me to blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BCOp.png)

What my be the problem? And how can I fix it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to build the app then cd into the dist and then **cd (again) into the built app** before *http-server -p 8080*. The tutorial i followed had just mentioned to cd into the dist and serve, so it wasn't very clear.

Comment: I make this to make it work:

1. npm run ng build inside app main directory
2. cd dist, cd my_project_name
3. http-server -p 8080 inside my_project_name
4. open http://127.0.0.1:8080/ on the browser (or click the terminal)

Angular v16, http-server V14.1.1

Answer (score 6):

I am also facing this problem in **Angular6** but it can be solved by following steps

1. Make a dist using `ng build --prod`
2. Then

```
cd dist
cd project_name
npx http-server
```

3. click any IP given after server starts, e.g. `127.0.0.1:8080`

Answer (score 1):

Seems you dist folder is empty. Please double check and make sure your build succeed.lite-server Thats what I use often to run my angular app. Take a look at this link https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-disk-serve.
The is that even if you use http-server when you reload the page it will show up a 404 error. Page not found. Best solution is using lite-server.

```
npm i lite-server -g
```

Then cd inside the root path of your application and run

```
lite-server --baseDir="dist"
```

Your app will run over port `3000` by default.
If you want to run it on a different port so take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35517817/6261137

Comment: The dist folder is not empty, i successfully installed lite-server and when i run ' lite-server --baseDir="dist" ' localhost:3000 displays the following message: Cannot GET /

Comment: It means you are having some issues with your build. Check your code. Make sure you have a default route. Can you show us your routing module ?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you started your dev server in the parent folder.

Did you build your app successfully ?

Comment: Yes i built it successfully. The 'ng serve' works fine. I started 'http-server -p 8080' in the dist folder